# Getting error in Bing Map Geocode service

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am new to windows development, I am developing an application in which I have to show the store location in Map. So I am using Bing map to show the stores. I am developing the application for Windows Phone 8.

But Lastly I got an error about Microsoft.Phone.Controls Version=8.0.0

So can anyone please solve my issue. My code part are like:

```
private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
    private GeoPositionAccuracy accuracy = GeoPositionAccuracy.High;
    private MapLayer pushpinLayer = null;
    Array LandMarkPositionArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(RssLandMark), 100);
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    int LandMarkCount = 0;
    int zoomLevel = 15;
    string LandMarkName = "";
    string LandMarkTitle = "";
public MapScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        startLocationService();
    }
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string msg = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
            LandMarkName = msg;
    }
private void startLocationService()
    {
        if (pushpinLayer == null)
        {
            pushpinLayer = new MapLayer();
            pushpinLayer.Name = "PushPinLayer";
            map1.Children.Add(pushpinLayer);
        }
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(accuracy);
        watcher.MovementThreshold = 50;
        watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
        watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
        watcher.Start();
    }
void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => myStatusChanged(e));
    }
void myStatusChanged(GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MessageBox.Show("location is unsupported on this device");
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MessageBox.Show("data unavailable");
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                break;
        }
    }
void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => myPositionChanged(e));
    }
void myPositionChanged(GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        MessageBox.Show(latitude.ToString());
        longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
        LoadLandMarkList();
    }
void LoadLandMarkList()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(LandMarkName + "" + LandMarkCount);
        //string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&radius=1000&name=" + LandMarkName + "&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCHKtTaHDzKtvDydDAVw1fv5PbnL69BGY0";
        string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&radius=50000&query=burial|flowers&types=funeral_home|florist&sensor=false&key=<google Api key>";
        WebClient xmlClient = new WebClient();
        xmlClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(LoadLandMarkList_Completed);
        xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
void LoadLandMarkList_Completed(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            LandMarkCount = 0;
            XElement xmlDataStill = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            foreach (var item in xmlDataStill.Descendants("result"))
            {
                string name = (string)item.Element("name").Value;
                string address = (string)item.Element("vicinity").Value;
                string latitude = (string)item.Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lat").Value;
                string longitude = (string)item.Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lng").Value;
                LandMarkPositionArray.SetValue(new RssLandMark() { name = name, address = address, longitude = longitude, latitude = latitude }, LandMarkCount);
                LandMarkCount++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(LandMarkName + "" + LandMarkCount);
            if (LandMarkCount > 0)
            {
                PlotUserAndLandMarks();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no information available for your location");
                progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
void PlotUserAndLandMarks()
    {
        //plot user
        Pushpin user = new Pushpin();
        user.Location = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
        Image pinImage1 = new Image();
        pinImage1.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/user.png", UriKind.Relative));
        pinImage1.Margin = new Thickness(-69, -52, 0, 0);
        pinImage1.Opacity = 0.8;
        pinImage1.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
        pushpinLayer.AddChild(pinImage1, user.Location);
        map1.SetView(user.Location, zoomLevel);
        //-----------------------------------------------
        //plot landmarks
        for (int i = 0; i < LandMarkCount; i++)
        {
            RssLandMark st = LandMarkPositionArray.GetValue(i) as RssLandMark;
            Pushpin landMark = new Pushpin();
            landMark.Location = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(st.latitude), Convert.ToDouble(st.longitude));
            if (st.name.Length > 8)
            {
                LandMarkTitle = st.name.Substring(0, 8) + "..";
            }
            landMark.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            landMark.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            landMark.Content = LandMarkTitle;
            landMark.FontSize = 21;
            landMark.Opacity = .9;
            landMark.Tag = i + "";
            landMark.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(showandMarkDetails_Completed);
            map1.Children.Add(landMark);
        }
        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
void showandMarkDetails_Completed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32((sender as Pushpin).Tag);
        RssLandMark st = LandMarkPositionArray.GetValue(id) as RssLandMark;
        title_txt.Text = st.name;
        address_txt.Text = st.address;
        dist_txt.Text = "You are around " + calcutaleDistance(latitude, longitude, Convert.ToDouble(st.latitude), Convert.ToDouble(st.longitude)) + " away";
        popup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        bg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
public static string calcutaleDistance(double ulat, double ulon, double lat, double lon)
    {
        var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(ulat, ulon);
        var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);
        var R = 6371;
        double lat1 = (sCoord.Latitude) / 180 * Math.PI;
        double lat2 = (eCoord.Latitude) / 180 * Math.PI;
        double lng1 = (sCoord.Longitude) / 180 * Math.PI;
        double lng2 = (eCoord.Longitude) / 180 * Math.PI;
        double dlng = lng2 - lng1;
        double dlat = lat2 - lat1;
        var a = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dlat / 2), 2) + Math.Cos(lat1) *
                         Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dlng / 2), 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(a)));
        var d = R * c;
        return (String.Format("{0:0.00}", d) + " km");
    }
void Close_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        bg.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO : Change map view mode.
        if (map1.Mode is AerialMode)
        {
            map1.Mode = new RoadMode();
        }
        else
        {
            map1.Mode = new AerialMode(true);
        }
    }
```

I used the code for Windows Phone 7.1, its working fine. But I am getting a problem when I am writing the same code for Windows Phone 8. I have added Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll file also. Its giving an error which I pasted as image along with this post.

Along with this I am using another class naming RssData.cs. This class I am using to store the data and then to display all the data from that class when needed.

```
public class RssData
{
}
public class RssLandMark
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Error]

So please if anyone can solve it please help me out. 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Comment: Actually I used some Google Api thats why I thought like that

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the correct assemblies? I get this sometimes when I upgrade a wp7.5 project to wp8 within visual studio. is the map control DLL pointing to a location such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0? Remove the refrence and try adding it again after upgrading your project, the add reference dialogue should only display a list of compatible Assemblies.